Access the channel output associated to a language server trace
As part of an extension I am developing, I would like to access the output channel associated to the trace of my language server, or even better its file so that I could open it either through the
channel.show(); command or through a workbench action such as vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.openLogFile", file).
For context I create the LanguageClient as

export default class Client extends LanguageClient {

    constructor(
        serverOptions: ServerOptions,
        clientOptions: LanguageClientOptions,
    ) {
        super(
            'lanuage-server',
            'Language Server',
            serverOptions,
            clientOptions
        );
    }

[...]

}

I cannot figure out how to gain access to it.
I cannot find the right API calls. If I create a channel myself it is easy enough to access, but I don't know how to gain access to this one which is created automatically.
Any insight would be much appreciated.
